# Text classification using Word2Vec

Tags: python, word2vec

I am in trouble to understand Word2Vec. I need to do a help desk text classification, based on what users complain in the help desk system. Each sentence has its own class.

I've seen some pre-trained word2vec files in the internet, but I don't know if is the best way to work since my problem is very specific. And my dataset is in Portuguese.

I'm considering that I will have to create my own model and I am in doubt on how to do that. Do I have to do it with the same words as the dataset I have with my sentences and classes?

In the frst line, the column titles. Below the first line, I have the sentence and the class. Could anyone help me? I saw Gensin to create vector models, and sounds me good. But I am completely lost.

> : chamado,classe 'Prezados não estou conseguindo gerar uma nota fiscal
>   do módulo de estoque e custos.','ERP GESTÃO', 'Não consigo acessar o
>   ERP com meu usuário e senha.','ERP GESTÃO', 'Médico não consegue gerar
>   receituário no módulo de Medicina e segurança do trabalho.','ERP
>   GESTÃO', 'O produto 4589658 tinta holográfica não está disponível no
>   EIC e não consigo gerar a PO.','ERP GESTÃO',

Answer (score 0):

Your inquiry is very general, and normally StackOverflow will be more able to help when you've tried specific things, and hit specific problems - so that you can provide exact code, errors, or shortfalls to ask about.

But in general:

- You might not need word2vec at all: there are many text-classification approaches that, with sufficient training data, may assign your texts to helpful classes without using word-vectors. You will likely want to try those first, then consider word-vectors as a later improvement.
- For word-vectors to be helpful, they need to be based on your actual language, and also ideally your particular domain-of-concern. Generic word-vectors from news articles or even Wikipedia may not include the important lingo, and word-senses for your problem. But it's not too hard to train your own word-vectors – you just need a lot of varied, relevant texts that use the words in realistic, relevant contexts. So yes, you'd ideally train your word-vectors on the same texts you eventually want to classify.

But mostly, if you're "totally lost", start with more simple text-classification examples. As you're using Python, examples based on scikit-learn may be most relevant. Adapt those to your data & goals, to familiarize yourself with all the steps & the ways of evaluating whether your changes are improving your end results or not. Then investigate techniques like word-vectors.

Comment: Helped me a lot. Thanks. Since I was not sure about using a pre-treined wordvec file or build my own (even if I had a suspicious), I did not start doing it. So now I will start implementing somehting using w2v and will have more specific doubts, concerening implementation. In fact, I have already implemented other approaches and you are correct, the results are very good.